# Sorting List throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, tomcat, collections, jersey, jetty

The following innocent API call crashes the entire Jersey web application.

```
@Path("/sortlist")
public class SortList {
   @GET
   public void sort() {
       List<Dog> test = new ArrayList<>();
       test.add(new Dog("test"));
       test.add(new Dog("blah"));
       test.sort(Comparator.comparing(Dog::getName));
   }

   class Dog {
       private String name;
       public String getName() { return name; }
       public Dog(String name) { this.name = name; }
   }
}
```

It throws

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-serlvet threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)

root cause
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20343
org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

But why? Even synchronizing the sorting operation has no effect. Could this be a bug in one of the following technologies? Can you duplicate this problem?

- Tomcat 7.0.73
- Jersey 1.19.3
- Jetty 9.4.0.v20161208
- ASM 5.0.4

Comment: Well that stack trace looks like the exception is in the constructor for `ClassReader`, not your class... what makes you think it's got anything to do with your `sort()` method?

Comment: Since this method alone crashes the Application, nothing else. Apparently, Jersey does not support Java 8 well enough. I've posted my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a Jersey Bug 1.X, as it does not support Java 8 well enough. Upgrading to Jersey 2.X solves this problem.

A Solution for jersey 1.X to this would be using a Java 7 approach for sorting.

```
Collections.sort(test, new Comparator<Dog>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Dog o1, Dog o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
});
```